# Symfony2 Payum Bundle - Call to undefined method isCaptured()

Tags: symfony, payum

I try to make Paypal Express Checkout exacly like it's here: 
https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/symfony/custom-purchase-examples/paypal-express-checkout.md
https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/symfony/purchase-done-action.md

Everything works expect that captureDoneAction returns error:

> Error: Call to undefined method
>   Payum\Core\Request\GetHumanStatus::isCaptured() in
>   (..)/PaymentBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 65

(..) is just my path and line 65 is:

> if ($status->isCaptured()) {

everything else is just like in the example in Payum Documentation. Why isCaptured() returns an error?

Comment: what version of payum are you using? Seems like the CAPTURED status was added in the 0.12 version (see : https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) so if you use a lower version update it or use the SUCCESS status instead

Comment: for some wierd reason in doc for version 0.11 there are links for doc for version 0.12, now I see that in the links I attached. Thanks :)

Comment: I'll try to fix it, not easy to do though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Coussinsky, answer to this question is very easy.
In documentation there is a mix-up of versions if you follow the links in the bottom of the `http://payum.org/doc/0.11/PayumBundle/simple_purchase_examples/paypal_express_checkout` (https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/symfony/custom-purchase-examples/paypal-express-checkout.md)